# Pagination : First, Next, Previous, Last

Tags: php, pagination

I want to create a pagination system. I don't know how create the first page and last page ??? I have arrived for the page "previous" and "next".

first | << previous | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | next >> | last

Here is my code:

```
if($pageCourante!=1)
{
    $precedant = $pageCourante-1; 
    echo'<a href="index.php?page='.$precedant.'">«Precedant»</a>'; 

}


for($i=1; $i<=$pageTotal; $i++) 
{
  echo'<a href="index.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';       
}

if($pageCourante<$pageTotal){
    $suivant= $pageCourante+1;
    echo'<a href="index.php?page='.$suivant.'">«Suivant»</a>';   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming page 1 is the first page:

```
echo '<a href="index.php?page=1">First</a>';
```

And assuming `$pageTotal` is the last page ID:

```
echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$pageTotal.'">Last</a>';
```

Comment: Why would you loop again? You would just put the "first" before your "previous" logic, and the "last" after your "next" logic. It doesn't need to loop.